# How to draw a line between two circles?

Tags: diagrams, asymptote

I want to create a graph using Asymptote and this graph consists of quite some circles with lines between them. Let me give a small example using two circles.

```
pair a1=(4.5,2);
pair a2=(0,0);
real r=0.25;

path c1=circle(a1,r);
path c2=circle(a2,r);

draw(c1);
draw(c2);
```

Now, I have tried several ways to draw a simple, though nice line:

```
draw(a1--a2, arrow=MidArrow(size=8));
draw(c1--c2, arrow=MidArrow(size=8));
draw(a1+(0,-r)--a2+(0,r), arrow=MidArrow(size=8));
```

None one of them gives the result I want. The first has line segments inside the circles, the second does not start the line at logical places and the third solution does not look natural. I would want the line `a1--a2`, so the shortest line between the two circles, but without the line segments inside the circles.

Is there a way to shorten this line by `r` at both sides? This way I do not have to calculate the exact coordinates of where the `a1--a2` line crosses the circle, since I want to be able to move the circles around.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like that?

A combination of `firstcut(p, c1).after` which removes the part of path `p` located *before* its intersection with `c1`, and of `lastcut(q, c2).before`, which removes the part of path `q` located *after* its intersection with `c2`. See Asympote's main manual, p. 35.

```
unitsize(2cm);
pair a1=(4.5,2);
pair a2=(0,0);
real r=0.25;

path c1=circle(a1,r);
path c2=circle(a2,r);

draw(c1);
draw(c2);
//draw(a1--a2, arrow=MidArrow(size=8));
draw(lastcut(firstcut(a1--a2, c1).after, c2).before, arrow=MidArrow(size=8));
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

@Franck has a fine general answer, but perhaps a simpler solution is to draw the arrow first, then draw AND fill the circles.

```
unitsize(1cm);
pair a1=(4.5,2);
pair a2=(0,0);
real r=0.25;

path c1=circle(a1,r);
path c2=circle(a2,r);

draw(a1--a2, arrow=MidArrow(size=8));

filldraw(c1, white);
filldraw(c2, white);
```

[image]

Comment: In this case it is indeed simpler, but if the arrow's tip had been located at the end of the line `a1--a2` as usual, it would have been partly erased by the filling of `c2`.