# Simple way to make circular arrow arc?

Tags: tikz-pgf, asymptote

I have 4 circle nodes with different sizes.

Is there a simple way (TikZ, Asymptote,...) to connected them with circular arrow arcs?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle,draw,fill=white}]
\def\r{3}
\draw[red] (0,0) circle (\r);

% 4 nodes with different sizes
\path
(180:\r) node (Sp) {Spring}
(90:\r)  node (Su) {Summer}
(0:\r)   node (Au) {Autumn}
(-90:\r) node (Wi) {Winter};

% How to make arrow arcs cicular? (the red one with arrow tips)
\begin{scope}[-stealth,bend left]
\draw (Sp) to (Su);
\draw (Su) to (Au);
\draw (Au) to (Wi);
\draw (Wi) to (Sp);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is one way to do it in `Asymptote` with true arcs.**

The `intersect` function returns an array of two `time`s where the two paths intersect.  The `subpath` function trims the arc to the intersection `time`s.

I have not wrapped the code into a LaTeX document because I tend to process Asymptote with the `asy` command.

```
unitsize(1inch);

path Autumn = shift( 1, 0)*scale(0.35)*unitcircle;
path Winter = shift( 0,-1)*scale(0.30)*unitcircle;
path Spring = shift(-1, 0)*scale(0.32)*unitcircle;
path Summer = shift( 0, 1)*scale(0.36)*unitcircle;

draw(Autumn);
draw(Winter);
draw(Spring);
draw(Summer);

label("Autumn", ( 1, 0));
label("Winter", ( 0,-1));
label("Spring", (-1, 0));
label("Summer", ( 0, 1));

path p1 = arc((0,0), 1, 0, -90);
draw(subpath(p1, intersect(p1,Autumn)[0], intersect(p1,Winter)[0]), red, Arrow);

path p2 = arc((0,0), 1, 270, 180);
draw(subpath(p2, intersect(p2,Winter)[0], intersect(p2,Spring)[0]), red, Arrow);

path p3 = arc((0,0), 1, 180, 90);
draw(subpath(p3, intersect(p3,Spring)[0], intersect(p3,Summer)[0]), red, Arrow);

path p4 = arc((0,0), 1, 90, 0);
draw(subpath(p4, intersect(p4,Summer)[0], intersect(p4,Autumn)[0]), red, Arrow);
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can compute the intersections of the node boundaries and the circle to draw the arcs. For your convenience, I packed all the stuff in a pic. I kept the red circle in to prove that the arcs perfectly cover it.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending,calc,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle,draw,fill=white},
 pics/circular arc/.style args={from #1 to #2}{code={
 \path[name path=arc] 
  let \p1=(#1),\p2=(#2),\n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)},\n2={atan2(\y2,\x2)},
    \n3={ifthenelse(abs(\n1-\n2)<180,\n2,\n2-360)}
  in (\n1:\r) arc(\n1:\n3:\r);
 \draw[-{Stealth[bend]},pic actions,
    name intersections={of=#1 and arc,by=arcstart},
    name intersections={of=#2 and arc,by=arcend}] 
    let \p1=(arcstart),\p2=(arcend),\n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)},\n2={atan2(\y2,\x2)},
     \n3={ifthenelse(abs(\n1-\n2)<180,\n2,\n2-360)}
  in (\n1:\r) arc(\n1:\n3:\r);
 }}]
\def\r{3}
\draw[red] (0,0) circle (\r);

% 4 nodes with different sizes
\path
(180:\r) node[name path=Sp] (Sp) {Spring}
(90:\r)  node[name path=Su] (Su) {Summer}
(0:\r)   node[name path=Au] (Au) {Autumn}
(-90:\r) node[name path=Wi] (Wi) {Winter};

% How to make arrow arcs cicular? (the red one with arrow tips)
\begin{scope}[-stealth,bend left]
 \path pic{circular arc=from Sp to Su}
    pic{circular arc=from Su to Au}
    pic{circular arc=from Au to Wi}
    pic{circular arc=from Wi to Sp};

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works well! also it's first time I see that we can use `name path` in a `node` (but it is reasonable because a `node` is also a `path`). One of my friend is writing Asymptote code. Let's wait and compare whose code is simpler!

Comment: @BlackMild You can make it much shorter if you make some assumptions on the node shapes and sizes. Here you could compute the intersection points analytically, and have a super short code. The current answer works for arbitrary node shapes and sizes. What are the precise boundary conditions of this game?

Answer (score 3):

This is what the `graphdrawing` [library `necklace routing`](https://tikz.dev/gd-edge-routing) is made for.

### Code

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{
  arrows.meta, bending,  % for Stealth arrow tips and bended arrow tips
  graphs, graphdrawing}  % for \graph syntax and \usegdlibrary → needs LuaTeX
\usegdlibrary{
  circular,        % for simple necklace layout
  routing}         % for necklace routing
\tikzgraphsset{
  circ routing/.style={
    /tikz/>={Stealth[sep,bend]},
    nodes={draw, circle},
    radius=3cm,
    ->, cycle,              % all edges are directed, last connects to first
    simple necklace layout, % place nodes on a circle
    grow'=down,             % first node is at the top, ' = clockwise
    necklace routing}}      % make connections follow the circle
\begin{document}
\tikz\graph[circ routing]{Summer, Autumn, Winter, Spring};
\end{document}
```

### Output (with circle of radius 3cm added)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[every node/.style={circle,draw,fill=white}]
\def\r{3}
%\draw[red] (0,0) circle (\r);

% 4 nodes with different sizes
\path
(180:\r) node (Sp) {Spring}
(90:\r) node (Su) {Summer}
(0:\r) node (Au) {Autumn}
(-90:\r) node (Wi) {Winter};

\begin{scope}[-stealth,red,bend left]
\draw (Sp.90) to (Su.180);
\draw (Su.0) to (Au.90);
\draw (Au.270) to (Wi.0);
\draw (Wi.180) to (Sp.270);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's a bit better, but still it is not circular arc (as you used [bend left] I guess)

Answer (score 2):

I have just found a seem-to-be-simple way with `angles` library. Every circular arrow arc is an angle mark.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle,draw,fill=white}]
\def\r{3}
\draw[red] (0,0) circle (\r);

% 4 nodes with different sizes
\path
(0,0) coordinate (O)
(180:\r) node (Sp) {Spring}
(90:\r)  node (Su) {Summer}
(0:\r)   node (Au) {Autumn}
(-90:\r) node (Wi) {Winter};

% Make arrow arcs cicular using angles library as angle mark
\path
(Sp.north) coordinate (SpN)
(Su.west) coordinate (SuW)
pic[draw=blue,fill=none,stealth-,angle radius=\r cm]{angle=SuW--O--SpN}
(Su.east) coordinate (SuE)
(Au.north) coordinate (AuN)
pic[draw=blue,fill=none,stealth-,angle radius=\r cm]{angle=AuN--O--SuE};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A short code with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}%

\begin{document}

    \begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
   \psset{unit=2, linejoin=1, arrowinset=0.1}
    \pscircle[linecolor=red](0,0){1}
    \psset{fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=white}
    \cnodeput[](1,0){A}{Autumn}
    \cnodeput(0,1){Su}{Summer}
    \cnodeput(-1,0){Sp}{Spring}
    \cnodeput(0,-1){W}{Winter}
    \foreach\S/ \T in{Su/A, A/W, W/Sp, Sp/Su}{\ncarc[arcangle=22, arrows=->]{\S}{\T}}
    \end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have just found another Asymptote way from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/245959/140722) by Franck Pastor using `firstcut` and `lastcut`.

[image]

```
unitsize(1cm);
real R=3;
pair A=R*dir(180);
pair B=R*dir(90); 

dot(A^^B);
real rA=1, rB=1.5;
draw(circle((0,0),R),gray);
path cA=circle(A,rA);
path cB=circle(B,rB);

draw(cA^^cB);
path AB=arc((0,0),R,180,90);
draw(lastcut(firstcut(AB, cA).after, cB).before, red,arrow=Arrow(size=8));

shipout(bbox(5mm,invisible));
```