# Drawing a circle graph with TIKZ with foreach placement and paths, yet the inbound for edges is off

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I want to draw a circle using TIKZ and instead of manually placing the nodes and connecting the nodes I wanted to use loops as any sane person would. Now when I wrote these, the incoming edge seems to be going to some point slightly of the node instead of to its core.

In the example, I included a version with the path manually written out. I am losing my sanity here :D
Anyone got any idea as to what is happening here?
Any style critique is also very welcome!

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{automata}
                
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes=state]
\def \number {8}
\def \radius {2cm}
\def \degree {360/\number}

\foreach \s in {1,...,\number}
{
    \node at ({\degree * (\s -1)}:\radius) (\s) {$u_\s$};
}

\foreach \s in {1,...,\number}
{
    \pgfmathsetmacro\result{Mod( (\s), \number)+1}
    \path (\s) edge[bend right = 15] (\result);
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes=state]
\def \number {8}
\def \radius {2cm}
\def \degree {360/\number}

\foreach \s in {1,...,\number}
{
    \node at ({\degree * (\s -1)}:\radius) (\s) {$u_\s$};
}

          \path (1) edge[bend right = 15] (2)
%                   edge (5)
                (2) edge[bend right = 15] (3)
%                   edge (6)
                (3) edge[bend right = 15] (4)
%                   edge (7)
                (4) edge[bend right = 15] (5)
%                   edge (8)
                (5) edge[bend right = 15] (6)
                (6) edge[bend right = 15] (7)
                (7) edge[bend right = 15] (8)
                (8) edge[bend right = 15] (1)
                    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need `\pgfmathtruncatemacro\result{Mod( (\s), \number)+1}` to drop `.0` at the end of the number. `\foreach \s [evaluate=\s as \result using {int(Mod( (\s), \number)+1)}]in {1,...,\number}
{
    \path (\s) edge[bend right = 15] (\result);
}` also works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\result{Mod( (\s), \number)+1}
```

to drop `.0`, which gets interpreted as a node anchor (the east anchor). Or use `evaluate` with `int`.

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
                
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes=state]
\def \number {8}
\def \radius {2cm}
\def \degree {360/\number}

\foreach \s in {1,...,\number}
{
    \node at ({\degree * (\s -1)}:\radius) (\s) {$u_\s$};
}

\foreach \s [evaluate=\s as \result using {int(Mod( (\s), \number)+1)}]in {1,...,\number}
{
    \path (\s) edge[bend right = 15] (\result);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: BTW, if you are interested in *exact* circular arcs *without* overpainting stuff with white, look at e.g.  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/512539.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something stupid like this, just not what :)
Could you elaborate on why you use evaluate over macros?
I find the syntax rather ugly/unintuitive.

Answer (score 1):

If if the problem is just to arrange the circles on the circle, this can be done relative simple:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=10pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
C/.style = {circle, draw, fill=white, minimum size=7mm, 
            inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}
                        ]
\def \number {8}
\def \radius {2cm}
\def \degree {360/\number}
% circle
\draw   (0,0)   circle[radius=\radius];
% nodes on circle
    \foreach \i [count=\j from 0] in {1,...,\number}
\node (n\i) [C] at (\j*\degree:\radius) {$u_\i$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or do I miss/misunderstood something?

Comment: This does not answer the question and overpaints things white, which can backfire terribly.

Comment: I will wait on OP comment. So far in question I didn't find requirement that nodes (circles) had to be transparent.

Comment: I mainly wanted to find out where this goes wrong. Painting circles and stuff is fine, I prefer real edges as those are extendable.
And this is not a one of thing I had to do, but more me learning how to do it correctly for the future, or well, asking others :D
Thanks though.

Comment: @Tenaka, thanks for comment. Apparently my answer is not what you looking for. Anyway, you should made your question more clear about this (that you not interested for simple solution which require white fill), but solutions proposed by *TikZling* (who is renomated expert for this :-) )