# How to draw a cycle graph with the help of Tikzit?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wanted to try using **"Tikzit"**  to create a cycle graph. But I have a little trouble. [Software download link](https://tikzit.github.io/)

It may be easy to use the existing tikz code.https://texample.net/tikz/examples/cycle/

```
% A simple cycle
% Author : Jerome Tremblay
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\def \n {5}
\def \radius {3cm}
\def \margin {6} % margin in angles, depends on the radius

\foreach \s in {1,...,\n}
{
  \node[draw, circle] at ({360/\n * (\s - 1)}:\radius) {$\s$};
  \draw[-, >=latex] ({360/\n * (\s -1)+\margin}:\radius) 
    arc ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:{360/\n * (\s)-\margin}:\radius);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

When I want to use Tikzit software, it seems difficult to draw above graph.

The key lies in the location of the vertex and the s**etting of the curvature of the curve**, which is very difficult for me. Don't know how to adjust them.

[image]

The following codes come from this software.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shapes.geometric,shapes.misc}

% these are dummy properties used by TikZiT, but ignored by LaTex
\pgfkeys{/tikz/tikzit fill/.initial=0}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/tikzit draw/.initial=0}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/tikzit shape/.initial=0}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/tikzit category/.initial=0}

% standard layers used in .tikz files
\pgfdeclarelayer{edgelayer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{nodelayer}
\pgfsetlayers{background,edgelayer,nodelayer,main}

% style for blank nodes
\tikzstyle{none}=[inner sep=0mm]

% Node styles
\tikzstyle{white_node}=[fill=white, draw=black, shape=circle]
\tikzstyle{blackedge}=[-, draw=black]

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{nodelayer}
            \node [style={white_node}] (0) at (5, 6) {};
            \node [style={white_node}] (1) at (7, 4) {};
            \node [style={white_node}] (2) at (5, 2) {};
            \node [style={white_node}] (3) at (3, 3) {};
            \node [style={white_node}] (4) at (3, 5) {};
        \end{pgfonlayer}
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{edgelayer}
            \draw [style=blackedge, bend left] (0) to (1);
            \draw [style=blackedge, bend left] (1) to (2);
            \draw [style=blackedge, bend right=330] (2) to (3);
            \draw [style=blackedge, bend left=45, looseness=0.75] (3) to (4);
            \draw [style=blackedge, bend left] (4) to (0);
        \end{pgfonlayer}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**  After a reminder from SebGlav , my question can actually be equivalent to this:

**How to use TikZ code to do that circle graph with proper edges?**

The circle is only part of my drawing, in fact I want to draw the following figure.
[image]

Comment: why would you want to draw with tikzit? direct drawing with TikZ is much better!

Comment: You try to draw bended edges between nodes instead of drawing a simple circle then the nodes. Why would you do this? TikZit could be of great help for complex graphs you don't seem to be able to create by hand but for this one? And if your question is "how would I do this on TikZit?", so it's not Ti*k*Z related. If you want a Ti*k*Z code to do that circle graph with proper edges, we can help you.

Comment: @BlackMild Actually this circle graph is part of my drawing and I need to add something else to the circle.  It would be better to be able to draw it on TikZit at one time.

Comment: @ SebGlav Thank you！ Your suggestion is very good. Maybe my question can be appropriately modified to this : How to use  TikZ code to do that circle graph with proper edges? This is indeed where I encountered difficulties.

Comment: this may be helpful https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511183/simple-way-to-make-circular-arrow-arc In fact, I did not get exactly what you want to draw.

Comment: @BlackMild Thank you very much!  I put what I want to draw in the question.

Comment: @licheng what is the position of P' ? do you think that you should clearly describe the figure ?

Comment: @BlackMild This is a graph in graph theory. The  P' is just a label, and its position does not need to be overly precise.

Comment: That said (and everyone here knows what a *graph* is, I presume), you don't really *need* your circle to be one ;) Whatever, Blackmild's answer below seems to fullfil your needs.

Comment: @ SebGlav You are right！ I don’t even need the cycle to be standard but for beautiful.   In my personal opinion, beautiful cycle  is also important for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my simple solution.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\def\r{2} 
\draw (0,0) circle(\r)
(0,0)--(90:\r)
(0,0)--(150:\r)
(0,0)--(-30:\r);

\foreach \point in {(0,0),(90:\r),(150:\r),(210:\r),(30:\r),(-30:\r),(-90:\r),(150:\r/3),(150:2*\r/3),(-30:\r/2),(90:\r/2)}
\draw[teal,fill=white] \point circle(.1);

\path
(0,0) node[below=1mm]{$\omega$}
(-30:\r) node[below right]{$u$}
(-30:\r/2) node[above=1mm]{$P'$}
(90:\r) node[above=1mm]{$z$}
(90:\r/2) node[left=1mm]{$P$}
(150:\r) node[left=1mm]{$y$}
(150:2*\r/3) node[below=1mm]{$x$}
(-90:\r) node[below=1mm]{$C$}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```