# "Rotating" a circular smartdiagram

Tags: smartdiagram

The code below builds a circular diagram. There is no arrow from 11 to 0. This is intentional.  However, I need the "0" node in the 12 o’clock position. Reordering the numbers in the `\smartdiagram` command rotates the nodes but removes the wrong arrow. The diagram must behave like a Ferris wheel---the bottoms of rectangular nodes should remain horizontal---so rotating the entire diagram will not work.

```
    \documentclass[]{standalone}
    \usepackage{smartdiagram}
    \smartdiagramset{circular distance=7.5cm,
    circular final arrow disabled=true,
    uniform color list=gray for 12 items,
    arrow tip=to,}
    \usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
    \begin{document}
    \smartdiagram[circular diagram:clockwise]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}%
    \end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Please remove the boldface unless it's needed on rare occasions: this way it's unpleasant to read. // I suggest including a screenshot, may be also with some sketch or visual indication of your verbal description. // Would also be nice, if you did some indention on the code. Thanks

Comment: Well, what I can tell you from having a look at how this is implemented, the problem is that the angle that defines the position of each of the nodes is defined as `180+360/\maxsmitem*\xi` where `\maxsitem` is the number of items and `\xi` is each individual item. That causes the position of the LAST element to always be at 180, while the first element shifts according to the number of items. It don't see how you could solve that other than redefining it in the package code...

Comment: It can be done using TikZ. For a reference here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511183/simple-way-to-make-circular-arrow-arc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple way to make circular arrow arc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511183/simple-way-to-make-circular-arrow-arc)

Answer (score 2):

So, as I explained in my comment above, your problem here is the definition of the angle that in turn defines the node position. To make sure, your first element is in the 12 o'clock position, you'll have to redefine the package code a bit. Since it is not advisable to do this in the actual package that is managed by your package manager here is what you can do:
Find the package files of the `smartdiagram` package. Copy and paste them into the directory of your `.tex` file. Open `smartdiagramlibrarycore.commands.code.tex` in your files' directory (**not the original one**) and change line 36 to `\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\angle}{270+360/\maxsmitem*(\xi-1)}`.

This will ensure that the angle of the first element is `90°` i.e. 12 o'clock.

Not very elegant, but it gets the job done.[image]

Comment: Maybe the package owner @Claudio Fiandrino can comment on wether this type of functionality already exists in the package and I just missed it.